# Bash sort tab delimited rows based on specific column with most values delimited by comma

Tags: bash, sorting

I have rows like so:

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 XM_017002478.2  stuff1,stuff2                           morestuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 XM_017002479.1  stuff1,stuff2,stuff3,stuff4,stuff5      morestuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 XR_001737138.1  stuff1,stuff2,stuff3                    morestuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 XR_001737478.1  stuff1,stuff2,stuff3,stuff4             morestuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 NC_426604.3     stuff1                                  morestuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 NC_426605.3     stuff1                                  morestuff
```

I would like to sort my rows by the 4th column for the desired output:

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 XM_017002479.1  stuff1,stuff2,stuff3,stuff4,stuff5      morestuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 XR_001737478.1  stuff1,stuff2,stuff3,stuff4             morestuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 XM_017002478.2  stuff1,stuff2                           morestuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 NC_426604.3     stuff1                                  morestuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 NC_426605.3     stuff1                                  morestuff
```

What is the best approach to achieve such result in bash ?

**Edit 1**: The column 4 shouldn't be sorted alphabetically. It has to be sorted according to the number of values found (delimited by commas).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

So this is a bit hacky, but it works.  I can't tell your delimeter (if it's tabs or spaces), but something like this will work, and allows for fairly easily manipulation:

```
 cat asdfasdf.txt | awk '{print gsub(/,/,","),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' | sort -r | cut -d' ' -f2,3,4,5,6
```

Now, there has got to be a way to do this entirely in `awk`, and I'm always in awe of the `awk` experts who know it so well.

I hope one of them puts together a more elegant command, but for now, this will help in a pinch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for late reply, I will get back to you when I test it out !